# Getting Root 0000

Tags: root

What is the Root Password.  I have tried the boot to recovery mode and I tried to change the root password and kept getting an authentication error.  This thing did not let me set the root password when I installed it.  I need root to install the Lamp stack and other things.  It's kind of useless unless I can get super user to do various admin functions.  Otherwise I'm just another user and I don't want to be just a user on my own machine.

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior of Ubuntu based distributions is to lock the root account to encourage the safer behavior of using `sudo` on individual commands that need escalated priveleges. That way you're not running as root all the time and it's a little safer.

There are a number of guides on the internet on how to install a LAMP stack on Ubuntu based distributions [like this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04). That should work for elementary too and you don't need to be logged in as root to do it. You just enter `sudo` in front of the commands and it prompts you for **your** user's password.

However, if you **really** still want to log in as root, you can use `sudo -i` and enter your password.

Answer (score 0):

never really used the above command "sudo -i" ... what I always do when needing root for a series of commands (because I am lazy and don't want to type sudo all the time) is just "sudo su -" ... sounds like it does the same as the above